# Flowing DIVs of complex objects

Tags: css

I lifted Pacman and Space Invaders (henceforth, collectively called "object") from [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) website, and I'm trying to flow them one after the other in a straight line (randomly), but there are jumps currently.

How would I wrap each object (Pacman or Space Invader) in this case, and make them flow?

Here's what I have so far, along with `float: left;` on every object:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ijraw
(refresh to see alternative renders)

**This is what I do want:**

*(all the DIVs flowing one after the other, one fluid line at a time)*

[image: do]

**This is what I don't want:**

*See the lone red Space Invader on line 2? I don't want that -- I want a line full of stuff.*

[image: dont]

PS there is too much code to post here. The Pacman and Space Invader objects aren't uniform, nor similar in any way, which is why I'm wondering if there's a way to wrap them with something more consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating divs will find their place in the DOM flow. Your two images are different sizes so floating is actually doing it's job.

Simply change `float : left` to `display : inline-block` and it should work.

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uapkL

Comment: Ah, I see. (I'll change ```ng-scope``` in your example to be a defined class). Thanks for that :)